# Library that sends statistics about how users set my app's preferences

Tags: android, open-source, reporting

## Context

My Android application has tons of preferences. You can customize everything single small thing.
This is more and more criticized, because it has become very hard to find the option you want, or understand what does what.

I have decided to remove about half of the preferences. Before doing this, I would like to get an idea of what preferences are widely used, and which ones are seldom used.

## Solution

I am looking for a solution that would gather for each preference, how many users have modified it from its default value.

## Requirements

- Integrates with the standard Android preferences dialog.
- Opt-in. Maybe a dialog that pops up once every 6 months to ask whether it is OK to send this data or not. I am happy with collection only happening at that time, once every six months is enough.
- Send data to Google Docs or Google App Engine or something similarly free. Scalable to a few hundred thousands users.
- Open source client-side library. Bonus for AGPL server-side.
- Do not collect any other data, only preferences, maybe Android version but certainly not the IP or anything that could identify the user.

Comment: I would personally if the preferences already exist just make less important/used ones hidden but still available for advanced users/those that do want those customization rather than removing them.

Comment: @NickWilde: Indeed, that is another approach I am considering. The library described in my question would help in this case as well.